# Not loading/working http://localhost:3000 in meteor

Tags: meteor, localhost

I am noob in meteor js. But  iwant to try it.

I have set up meteorjs using VM and vagrant in Windows.

I already started or run the meteor app.

But when im trying to load localhost:3000/ on chrome or firefox. its not working.

Please help me...

I follow this https://docs.google.com/document/d/1zwr3qEDsosUGgulYuQQ-0umnDgQtl8BUkKNySOCHMPM/edit

Answer (score 0):

You can try this development VM setup:
[Development vm](https://github.com/gfk-ba/meteor-dev-vm)

Put your meteor application in the app directory.